# java web start to spawn a process

Tags: java, process, java-web-start, spawn

I have a java webstart application that should be use on LAN private network website so its not for public usage. What i am trying is to spawn a command line window through the webstart application by calling this api

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c cd \""+strGenFolder+"\" & start cmd.exe /k \""+strCommandParas1+" \"");
```

This works fine without webstart through jar file but in webstart it does not give any error nor it crash but it doesn't work at all. Please correct me if there is any way to spawn a process in webstart even though i have given all permission in its jlnp file.

```
<security>
    <all-permissions/>
</security>
```

I don't have much experience in webstart so bear with me if i am talking silly. Your guidance can help me better

Comment: "*it does not give any error nor it crash but it doesn't work at all*" => you should add some logging and make sure you don't swallow any exceptions. You can spawn a new process from a webstart application running with `all-permissions`.

Comment: thanks you were right , the error was cache which were not displaying correct version..

Comment: Please write that up as an answer & accept it, or delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cache in windows make problem in running the correct version of jws, to solve this you have to delete the cache folder.

go in the following directory 
C:\Users\ssc1\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment and remove cache folder. Then refresh your web page and run your webstart, it will show you the updated version of your jws app.